# web.py how to get message from request when the contentType is 'text/xml'

Tags: python, web.py

My situation is : A server send a request to me, the request's contentType is 'text/xml', and the request content is an xml. First I need to get the request content. But when I use 'web.input()' in 'POST' function, I couldn't get any message, the result just is ''. I know web.py can get form data from a request, so how I can get message from request when the contentType is 'text/xml' in POST function. Thanks!

Comment: What URL and what method is used by "the server"? Maybe this data aint simply there. Be more specific pls.

Answer (score 1):

Use `web.data()`.